# A question about the hashCode function of AbstractList in java

Tags: java

At line 540, why could we use this pointer of AbstractList in foreach?

```java
538. public int hashCode() {
539.     int hashCode = 1;
540.     for (E e : this)
541.         hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
542.     return hashCode;
543. }
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igNx0.png)

Comment: It is using an enhanced-for-loop, not foreach.

Comment: you can use `this` because this is a virtual method, which means the receiver is the instance. There is no pointer in java.

Answer (score 0):

It iterates over the list items and create a hash code depended for that. For every item you add or remove from list changes hashcode. This is the default implementation to create uniqueness for a list.

Answer (score 0):

The question can be divided in two parts:

---

*"why could we use this pointer of AbstractList"*

`this` always *returns* the actual instance; it is also valid in an `abstract` class, being similar, in that case, to a parameter defined as `AbstractList this` initialized with the actual instance. Like in:

```
public int hashCode(AbstractList this) {
    ...
}
```

See [JLS 15.8.3. this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3) for more details.

---

*"why could we use ... AbstractList in foreach"*

the `AbstractList` can be used in the enhanced `for` loop because it implements the `Iterable` interface. See  documentation [JLS 14.14.2. The enhanced for statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2):

> The type of the Expression must be a subtype of the raw type Iterable or an array type

and of [Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html):

> Implementing this interface allows an object to be the target of the enhanced for statement (sometimes called the "for-each loop" statement).